# Unique expression as disjoint union of indecomposable subsets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A \to A$ be a function, we say that $B \subseteq A$ is $f$-invariant iff $f(B) \subseteq B $. We say that an invariant subset is indecomposable iff it cannot be expressed as a union of non-empty invariant subsets.

Is it true that $A$ has a unique expression as disjoint union of indecomposable invariant subsets ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider, for all $x \in A$, the sets $B_x = \displaystyle\bigcap \{B \subseteq A: x \in B \text{ and $B$ is invariant}\}$.